# Eclipse Window Builder I Can't Put Any Components

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I just installed Eclipse and i watched like 5 or 6 videos telling me to do the exact same thing so i did. Successfully opened a project, wrote hello world. But when i tried to use swing window builder. It just didn't work. I installed it the components and everything is there but when i try to select the components they just get selected and when i try to put them nothing reacts with my mouse, on the other side everyones window puts a red line or a green space to react. Mine just doesnt do that its like dead.

[you can see that multiple components are selected because i cant deselect too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dVZN.png)

I mean what can i do besides what i tried already:

- Opened a new project
- Opened new windows and tried both jframe and application window modes

These didn't work. Should i install again? Thank you already.

java 17 eclipse 2023-12 windowbuilder latest(?)

edit: I managed to add a button from the script but i cant still see it:
[It should have be seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ySXp.png)
edit: Now i can see the button it was about size of it but the drag and drop-like function of the eclipse still doesnt work. I can move the button around but i cant add another button there.